# Error on Build Phonegap project

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a next problem. I have VS 2013 Professional and have downloaded latest Phonegap version from official site - 2.9.12

I copied the project templates to the VS templates folder - they show up and i can create them, but i can't launch them it prompts:

[image]

Has anyone faced this?

P.S. Nothing has been modified, ans in older versions ( i think back in those days it was 1.7.x ) all worked fine.

Comment: 2.9.12 was released in Nov 2013 and severely deprecated. You should follow the steps on that website to install the PhoneGap CLI for the latest version of PhoneGap (4.0.x).

Comment: i installed Phonegap via CMD and Node, added a platform - the solution has been created. When i open it, i get same error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found an answer to this question. The installation of Update 4 of VS 2012 helped me - don't have any idea why if i have VS 2013, but it resolved the issue.